# Highcharts remove space around boxplot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is is possible to remove unnceccesary space on the chart that are extra value labels? I want the chart only consist of the plot values not the extra points on the axes. 
I tried adding

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
          pointPlacement: "on"
        }
      }
```

But it does not seem to work for horizontal boxlot in highcharts.
Here is the sandbox that you can use to see that there are extra values on the left and on the right of the boxplot and I want them removed. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-7gt0u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to play with [`yAxis` Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis) properties.

For example, if you're playing with `tickInterval` it'll render something like that, with a gap more or less important depending on the value you set:

[image: highcharts tickInterval prop]

But you also can disable the visibility of the last tick with `endOnTick`:

[image: playing with endOnTick prop]

I globally modified your chart configuration object with these properties:

```js
...
xAxis: {
  visible: false
},
yAxis: {
  min: 100,
  max: 411,
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  labels: {
    enabled: true
  },
  endOnTick: false,
  //tickInterval: 10,
},
...
```

Obviously, you can add a "dynamic" way to get min / max values of your data array to set them to `yAxis` min and max props.

[**Here's the modified version of your Sandbox example.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-5qyto)